# Yii2 авторизация и регистрация на одной странице

Tags: yii2

На одной странице происходит регистрация и авторизация. При авторизации происходит все нормально, заходит на главную и я могу выйти, но когда пытаюсь зарегистрироваться, происходит та же авторизация, т.е. работает по одному сценарию. Пытался сделать два сценария. Либо я не правильно понимаю как работает это, либо я где то в другом месте ошибаюсь.

Экшн в контроллере

```
 public function actionSignlog(){
   $this->layout = 'log';

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $loginModel = new LoginForm();
    $signupModel = new SignupForm();
    if ($loginModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $loginModel->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('signlog', [
            'loginModel' => $loginModel,
            'signupModel' => $signupModel
        ]);
    }
}
```

Форма логина в view

```
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

            <?=  $form->field($loginModel, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($loginModel, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

            <?= $form->field($loginModel, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>

            <div style="color:#999;margin:1em 0">
                Если вы забыли пароль, вы можете <?= Html::a('сбросить', ['site/request-password-reset']) ?> его
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Войти', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

форма регистрации в view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'signup-form']); ?>

<?= $form->field($signupModel, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($signupModel, 'email') ?>

<?= $form->field($signupModel, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Зарегистрироваться', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не используете модель регистрации, в этом и есть проблема. Сделайте так:

```
public function actionSignlog(){
   $this->layout = 'log';

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $loginModel = new LoginForm();
    $signupModel = new SignupForm();
    if ($loginModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $loginModel->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else if ($signupModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $signupModel->signup()) { //Или метод тот который вы испольуйте для регистрации
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    return $this->render('signlog', [
            'loginModel' => $loginModel,
            'signupModel' => $signupModel
    ]);
}
```